# excel vba run-time error 1004 - not clear why

Tags: excel, vba, runtime

I get the run-time error by running this code:

```
    For Each cell In Range("B1").EntireColumn.Cells
        If cell.Value = ListBox1.Value Then
            FIng(i) = cell.Row
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next cell

    For i = 0 To UBound(FIng)
        If Cells(FIng(i), 1).Value > 0 Then 'error: application defined 1004
            MsgBox (Cells(FIng(i), 1).Value)
        End If
    Next i
```

The error occurs in the line with the comment. What I am doing is check if a certain value is in a column, then save the column row in an array. The next loop is using this array to access a value in the first column and show it. It works but I get this error message and I don't know why.

Comment: did you try to debug `Cells(FIng(i), 1).Value`?

Comment: What is 'FIng'? What is the initial value for 'i'?

Comment: FIng is initialized as a ten element array. Since I am only interested in the row numbers (which are always greater than zero) I have to check first. All other Fing values are zero. But I can't see why this would cause an error.

Comment: Ah I think I know the problem. I should only check Fing and not value.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct second for loop:

```
For i = 0 To UBound(FIng)
    If FIng(i) > 0 Then 'error: application defined 1004
        MsgBox (Cells(FIng(i), 1).Value)
    End If
Next i
```